# What is the difference between the f" and the format() method in python

Tags: python, string, methods

So i've tried the formats string methods in python but what are the differences between them? Which method is best for me?

example1:
`name = 'Dash'`

`print(f'Hello {name}!')`

example2:
`name = 'Dash'`

`print('Hello {}!'.format(name))`

Comment: There is no difference as you see. Both are string formatting options, with f-strings being newly introduced.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively both do the same thing.
The f you mention is an f-string which is available from python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

Print f is just a newer and easier way of inserting a variable into a string. I think it came in in python 3.6 . Both do really the same thing